# Accessing custom objects field when binding data

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind some data to a listview and I am dealing with the following issue:

My object type is **CartItem** which has a **product** field and a **Quantity** field.

Quantity is just a integer, but the **Product** is also a **model** which has a long ID, string ImageUrl and a bunch of other fields.

I am trying to bind the data inside the Product to my listview like this:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding CartItem.Product.Image}">
```

But it's not working.

Is there a way I can access this via XAML file or I must write some explicit code?

[EDIT]:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    var stack = Navigation.NavigationStack;

    MainPage mainPage = (MainPage)stack[0];

    List<CartItem> cartList = mainPage.cart;

    //DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert(cartList[0].product.Image);

    BindingContext = cartList;

    CartListView.ItemsSource = cartList;

    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

FIXED WITH:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding product.Image}"
```

Comment: This should be able to work, are you sure that product and image are filled at the time of the binding? Did you set your BindingContext?

Comment: In addition; are they public properties?

Comment: The list is populated at the time of binding. Also the properties are public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your ItemsSource is a `List<CartItem>`, then each element in your list is an instance of `CartItem`, therefore the binding expression should be

```
Source="{Binding Product.Image}"
```

also note that in your commented out example, you are using "p"roduct instead of "P"roduct - be sure you use the one that matches the naming of your property

Comment: Hello Jason! Thank you soooo much for your answer. Indeed the problem was with capitalization of "p". Now it works!